# PHP Post Request trims trailing ] character?

Tags: php, http-post

I get this weird behaviour! I have a post request with entries like the following (HEAD of the request)

> reservation[a61517a3-228b-09a9-3872-aaab4e512b4c][RoomTypeReservation[start]]:22/06/2013

in PHP when I var_dump $_REQUEST I see something like

```
[reservation] => Array
    (
        [a61517a3-228b-09a9-3872-aaab4e512b4c] => Array
            (
                [RoomTypeReservation[start] => 22/06/2013
```

obviously the last ] (next to [start]) has been removed! I've also checked the source field of the form which bares the name of

> reservation[93a6539a-883a-3972-f96b-a24294bd682f][RoomTypeReservation[start]]

which is exactly what I see in the request header and is correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: Form fields can be made to behave like arrays so this is tipical behavoir

Comment: I have solved my issue already, what I am trying to figure out is the behaviour of PHP in the occasion. Obviously the issue as I indicate above is that PHP removes the last ] character hence it cannot comprehend the [xxxxxx[xxx]] as array. Question is why ;)